# Error Code: 1054 in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I created a table in mySQL database 'payroll' as:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`userName` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(15) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I'm getting error

> 1054(Unknown column 'Imran' in the 'field list')

on following line of code:

`insert into payroll.users SET userName=Imran`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the word Imran should be encapsulated by '-s to mark it's a string.

```
insert into payroll.users SET userName='Imran'
```